# Converting generics used in collections?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, polymorphism

Let's say I want to create diet plans for pet owners to keep their pets healthy and I have the following classes:

```cs
// Pets
public class Pet { ... }
public class Dog : Pet { ... }
public class Cat : Pet { ... }

// Meals and diets
public class Meal<T> : ICollection<T> where T : Pet
{
    ...
    private List<T> allowedPets { get; set; } = new List<T>();
    ...
}
public class Diet<T> : ICollection<Meal<T>> where T : Pet
{
    ...
    private List<Meal<T>> dietMeals { get; set; } = new List<Meal<T>>();
    ...
}
```

While I could have a list of pets that can follow a certain diet, rather than a list of pets that are allowed to have certain meals, this is just an example. Either way, I could make some arbitrary diets like these to use them in some sort of application.

```cs
// Dogs and their diets
Dog labrador = new Dog() { ... };
Dog dalmatian = new Dog() { ... };
Meal<Dog> mediumDogBreakfast = new Meal<Dog>(...) { labrador, dalmatian };
Meal<Dog> mediumDogLunch = new Meal<Dog>(...) { labrador, dalmatian };
Meal<Dog> mediumDogDinner = new Meal<Dog>(...) { labrador, dalmatian };
Diet<Dog> mediumDogDiet = new Diet<Dog>()
{
    mediumDogBreakfast,
    mediumDogLunch,
    mediumDogDinner
};

// Cats and their diets
Cat siamese = new Cat() { ... };
Cat sphynx = new Cat() { ... };
Meal<Cat> orientalCatBreakfast = new Meal<Cat>(...) { siamese, sphynx };
Meal<Cat> orientalCatLunch = new Meal<Cat>(...) { siamese, sphynx };
Meal<Cat> orientalCatDinner = new Meal<Cat>(...) { siamese, sphynx };
Diet<Cat> orientalCatDiet = new Diet<Cat>()
{
    orientalCatBreakfast,
    orientalCatLunch,
    orientalCatDinner
};
```

But if I then want to put these diets into a single list, I get a conversion error:

```cs
// This isn't allowed!
List<Diet<Pet>> = new List<Diet<Pet>>()
{
    mediumDogDiet,
    orientalCatDiet
};
```

I was under the impression that the list would allow `Cat` and `Dog` objects because the `Pet` costraint is more general, but apparently there's something going wrong here. How can I alter my `Pet` class or the collection implementation to allow a list that can hold both dog and cat diets (or any other future pet derivative for that matter)?

Comment: What you want is co-variance but that's only allowed on interfaces and it's only allowed if the type only comes out of the interfaces API (return type, readonly property) and does not go in (parameter, property with public set).  However since your classes are also `ICollection` that will not work as that allows the types to go in.  Imagine you did that cast then you could put Cats into a Dog meal and vice versa.

Comment: No, you want the `Diet` to be co-variant on it's type.  So you'd need a `IDiet<out T>` and a `List<IDiet<Pet>>`

Comment: @juharr is correct. I'd add that your design is questionable in several ways. If `Meal` implements `ICollection<T>` it why does it expose a `public` `List<T>`?

Comment: The only reason I made them implement `ICollection` was to enumerate their respective lists by default while debugging, but I guess I could write methods that add and clear and all that jazz without `ICollection` and call it a day.

Comment: @JansthcirlU Again, it's not `Pet` that needs to be an interface, its the generic `Diet<T>` that you need an interface for.

Comment: I only saw your new comment while I was typing the last one, my bad. I'll give the diet interface a shot!

Comment: @JansthcirlU I am just saying that the underlying list shouldn't be exposed because it is confusing and error prone to be able to add and remove in 2 ways. It should be `private`

Comment: Oh, I see, yeah that makes sense.

Comment: See my answer for an example of the interfaces required for co-variance.

Comment: If you want people to use the `AllowedPets` property, which would likely be clearer, make it a readonly property. You should not do all of this work in order to facilitate debugging. Hell, just pin the property in Visual Studio, override `ToString` or, if you must, use use an attribute `[DebuggerDisplay("AllowedPets = {AllowedPets}")] public class Meal {}`

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't know that `DebuggerDisplay` existed, what's that called in C#? Any resources to learn more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need co-varience:

**Take note** that this means that you have to create a collection of the interface `IDiet`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{

    public class Pet {  }
    public class Dog : Pet {  }
    public class Cat : Pet { }

    // Meals and diets

    public interface IMeal<out T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T> where T : Pet
    {
    }

    public interface IDiet<out T> : IReadOnlyCollection<IMeal<T>> where T : Pet
    {
    }

    public class Meal<T> : Collection<T>, IMeal<T> where T : Pet
    {
        public List<T> AllowedPets { get; set; } = new List<T>();
    }
    public class Diet<T> : Collection<IMeal<T>>, IDiet<T> where T : Pet
    {
        public List<Meal<T>> DietMeals { get; set; } = new List<Meal<T>>();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog labrador = new Dog() { };
            Dog dalmatian = new Dog() { };
            Meal<Dog> mediumDogBreakfast = new Meal<Dog>{ labrador, dalmatian };
            Meal<Dog> mediumDogLunch = new Meal<Dog>{ labrador, dalmatian };
            Meal<Dog> mediumDogDinner = new Meal<Dog>{ labrador, dalmatian };
            Diet<Dog> mediumDogDiet = new Diet<Dog>()
            {
                mediumDogBreakfast,
                mediumDogLunch,
                mediumDogDinner
            };

            // Cats and their diets
            Cat siamese = new Cat() { };
            Cat sphynx = new Cat() { };
            Meal<Cat> orientalCatBreakfast = new Meal<Cat>(){ siamese, sphynx };
            Meal<Cat> orientalCatLunch = new Meal<Cat>(){ siamese, sphynx };
            Meal<Cat> orientalCatDinner = new Meal<Cat>(){ siamese, sphynx };
            Diet<Cat> orientalCatDiet = new Diet<Cat>()
            {
                orientalCatBreakfast,
                orientalCatLunch,
                orientalCatDinner
            };

            List<IDiet<Pet>> diets = new List<IDiet<Pet>>
            {
                mediumDogDiet,
                orientalCatDiet
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JansthcirlU, did this work out for you? Let me know if you ran into any issues.

Comment: Sorry, I was still busy trying to wrap my head around it, but your implementation definitely works.

Comment: Was there anything that you feel the answer is missing if you need time to wrap your head around it? Would be good to add if so.

Comment: No worries, your answer's clear, I'm just slow to understand ;)